# Svcutil generates duplicate fields for C# proxy class

Tags: c#, java, .net, web-services, interop

I have 2 simple classes on the web-service side (Java webservice):

```
class A implements Serializable
{
 protected int foo;
 public getFoo(){..};
 public setFoo(){..}
}
public class B extends A implements Serializable {...}
```

The point is that on client side SvcUtil generates a proxy C# class ProxyB inherited from ProxyA, it's OK, But, why the tool creates redundant **foo1 field in ProxyB** class while **foo field is created in parent ProxyA** class?

I'm totally confused, any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: You are generating the WCF code from WSDL/XSD, correct? Will you post a sample WSDL/XSD which illustrates the problem?